# Display all feeds using simplexml_load() using PHP

Tags: php, simplexml

I want to loop to get all feeds, but displaying only one

```
$url = "http://localhost/feeds/feeds.rss";

$xml = simplexml_load_file($url); 

    foreach($xml->item as $result){ 

        echo $result->description."<br>";

    }
```

RSS Feed is -

```
<channel>
    <title>/</title>
    <link>/</link>
    <atom:link type="application/rss+xml" href="/" rel="self"/>
    <description>/</description>
    <language>/</language>
    <ttl>/</ttl>
  <item>
    <title>/</title>
    <description>/</description>
    <pubDate>/</pubDate>
    <guid>/</guid>
    <link>/</link>
  </item>
  <item>
    <title>/</title>
    <description>/</description>
    <pubDate>/</pubDate>
    <guid>/</guid>
    <link>/</link>
  </item>
</channel>
```

Comment: You want to display only one or your problem is that only one is displayed? What does your feed look like?

Comment: I want to display all feeds, but it is only displaying one

Comment: What does the RSS look like`?

Comment: <channel>
    <title>/</title>
    <link>/</link>
    <atom:link type="application/rss+xml" href="/" rel="self"/>
    <description>/</description>
    <language>/</language>
    <ttl>/</ttl>
  <item>
    <title>/</title>
    <description>/</description>
    <pubDate>/</pubDate>
    <guid>/</guid>
    <link>/</link>
  </item>
  <item>
    <title>/</title>
    <description>/</description>
    <pubDate>/</pubDate>
    <guid>/</guid>
    <link>/</link>
  </item>
</channel>

Comment: "atom:link" - where is this prefix associated with an uri? Could you please copy&paste the _whole_ feed?

Answer (score -1):

The solution is:

```
foreach($xml->channel->item as $result){ 

        echo $result->description."<br>";

    }
```

Comment: I am not sure why this is down voted, but this works just fine, it works